# Using a proxy for NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, proxy, nsurlconnection

Is there any way to get the content of a webfile (namely a .html Document) using a proxy, which is not defined in the system settings? I know that NSURLConnection is the right way to download a web file into a variable and not into a file (for which we should use NSURLDownload), but I don't find a way to use a proxy for it.
Are there some unofficial APIs, Libraries or Classes or such I could use for what I want to do?
I'm not that pro in Mac Programming, so I'm searching for something more or less simple.

SideSwipe

Answer (score 5):

`NSURL` classes wont do this.  You need to drop down to `CFURL`.  From mailing list: 
[Re: Can NSURLConnection use Proxy Server?](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg21050.html)