# How to use a proxy server in objective-c when send a NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, nsurlrequest

I want to use the proxy server as below to send a request.But I don't know the way to use a proxy server in `objective-c`?
proxy server:

```
72.64.146.136: 3128
```

Can anyone tell me?Thank you sincerely!

Comment: You can check this other question for an example of how to do it: [Handling redirects with custom NSURLProtocol and HTTP proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361357/handling-redirects-with-custom-nsurlprotocol-and-http-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy by using `CFURL` but a much nicer option is to use a networking library such as AFNetworking which has proxy support in its API.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

For more on the `CFURL` approach, see [Using a proxy for NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776023/using-a-proxy-for-nsurlconnection)

Comment: occulus could you provide a link for how to set proxy settings in AFNetwork requests